# ExtensionOf RdlContract using SysOperation in AX7

Tags: visual-studio-2015, axapta, dynamics-ax7, dynamics-365-operations, sysoperationframework

I am trying to add a boolean filter field to a standard TaxTransDetailRdlContract using SysOperation framework.
I have made **ExtensionOf[classStr()]** classes of Controller, RdlContract and UIBuilder and I have no luck.
The main error for now is "*The value "parmFilter" is not found in the map.*"

 Anybody got the similar error and knows how to solve it?

Comment: Could you [edit] into your question which standard contract you are trying to extend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now the **ExtensionOf[classStr()]** is not supported. 
The ***class [className] extends [extensionClassName]*** should be used and the content of the class should be copy-pasted inside. 
Remember to attach all the needed referenced packages to your model.